# Which noSQL DB is suitable for fast querying of variable multiple fields?

Tags: java, performance, indexing, nosql

I have DB of 1B users, each user has multiple properties. For example:

```
{userid : 1, emails : {xx@xx.com, yy@yy.com, zz@zz.com}, countries : {Italy, France, USA}, food : {pasta}}
```

Each property can contain multiple values.

During the lifetime of the web app, I would like to add more properties, for example: car, color....

So generally, I will have 1B users, each one with 3-20 properties - every user will have its own subset of properties, out of 20 possible properties.

The most important things are:

1. To perform the following query as fast as possible:
   find me all users with email=xx@xx.com OR car=Mercedes OR food=pasta OR color=black OR color=blue OR userid=10 OR userid=20.
   In each query I will query different subset of properties.
2. To be able to add a new property to the DB quite easily. I.e. in some day I will want to add also 'Gender' property, and I want that the queries on this property will be fast.
3. Each user has only subset of the properties
4. The queries will be 'property=value'. I don't need queries such as 'property>value' or 'property start with value'. I treat all values as constant keys.
5. In many cases I will add new users, but the most important thing is to query them fast.
6. Should be persistent, scalable, with fail-over
7. If it's matter, my web app will be written in Java

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by fast?

Most database will do what you want as fast as they can. Unless you have specific latency requirements I would pick a popular nosql database like mongodb.

For higher performance, you can use an LDAP database which is designed for this type of queries.  They are particularly useful if you have of the order of 100K+ queries per second and 100K+ users.

Comment: I have to handle 15K/sec queries, and to answer each query in less than 10ms. regarding mongodb - I will have to create index on every one of the 20 properties. I don't know what are the implications of so many indexes on the size of the DB and on the overall performance

Comment: In that case I would consider using an LDAP database. http://www.openldap.org/pub/hyc/mdm-paper.pdf Note: each server can handle between 20K and 80K queries per second depending on the spec of the server with sub-millisecond response times. I have used Sun One Directory Server before, but any LDAP server should perform well.

Comment: I will check it out.
Can you think on additional noSQL DB that are suit for this mission? Cassandra, Couchbase, hbase, BigTable?

Comment: LDAP databases are specificly designed for storing and querying user and group based information.  As for other noSQL databases ... http://nosql-database.org/ youc an take your pick.

Comment: I see that the last open ldap version is from October 2007...
I'll have to look for different noSQL solution

Comment: Its worth noting that LDAP is a mature technology. Its been around a while and it works, so it doesn't need to have regular patches.